# Time taken to check all keys of encryption algorithms

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I have been studying encryption algorithms and was wondering the time it would to check all keys for the following implementations : AES, DES, 3DES.

For DES I know key sizes are 56 bit, so there are 2^ 56 possible keys.
Similarly for 3DES, considering 112 bit key sizes, are there actually 2^ 112 possible keys?

So if I have a system which can check 50 billion keys per second, how to find the time it would take to check all keys?

Comment: Any sequence of the right number of bits is a valid key for these algorithms (IIRC). Use that to work out the math of how long it will take to brute-force these systems.

Comment: Hint: It's one division.

Comment: @templatetypedef I've found some litterature given the above information has calculated an estimated time to check all keys for 112 bit 3DES to be 800 days? How is that possible?  Time taken for 112 bit = ((2 ^ 112) / (50 x 10^ 9) )/(3600 x 24 x 365) => 3.29 x 10^ 15 years

Comment: Take a big number calculator (e.g. python) and type: `2**56 / (50 * 10**9 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)` and you get the years.

Comment: @ArtjomB. for DES will the same formula work? ( substitituing 2^112)

Comment: @GerardJean Sure, why not. But it's bigger than in your literature. Are you sure they use the same numbers and assumptions?

Comment: @Artjom yes they are the same. I have one more question, since it will take million of years to crack 3DES, why is it obsolete? (as per your formula)

Comment: There are some attacks on 3DES that shorten its effective space (NIST designates it effective 80-bits). Still, 80 bits is still not really brute-forceable. But crypto is conservative. We assume attacks & hardware will get better. Crypto attacks are generally multiple order-of-magnitude attacks. So it goes from 30M years to 300k to 300 to a box full of custom ASICs and its 3 years. Changing algorithms takes a long time (decades), & things may need to stay secure for decades, so when we see the first cracks, we start the process of moving. There are better ones available now, so we use them.

Comment: Also, the underlying DES really is broken (very practical to brute force). Rather than just glomming on more layers like 3DES does (wasting energy, hardware space, etc), we'd rather move to a more secure basic algorithm (like Rijndael/AES). A major determining factor for crypto algorithms is how well they can be implemented in hardware.